# Flash выдает ошибку в библиотеке Box2d

Tags: box2d, flash, actionscript

Скачал библиотеку Box2d, запустил пару приложенных к ней примеров, и мне на оба из них выдает ошибку FLASH:

```
C:\******\Box2DFlashAS3 2.1a\Source\Box2D\Dynamics\b2World.as, Line 871 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: b2Fixture.
```

Так и не могу понять что делать?

Answer (score 1):

- в проект не включена библиотека Box2D c этим классом
- в класс не включен внешний класс с помощью директивы import